# Open Office document at a specific word and highlight it

Tags: search, replace, com, aspose

is there any way I could open an office document (Word, excel) with the cursor position at a specific string that is given as input ?

The requirement is part of a search and replace functionality and the client would like to open a document with the cursor positioned at the first occurrence of the search term. Highlighting it as well if possible. I have tried researching for this, but didn't find any helpful resources.

We are using Aspose and the Component Object Model (COM)

Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to search text using Aspose.Words and Aspose.Cells. You can also highlight the searched term in the search results. For example you can search in an excel document using **Worksheet.Cells.Find()** method. Once cell is found, it could be highlighted with any color using **Cell.SetStyle()** method. Please visit the following links for details on how to search and highlight text using Aspose.Words and Aspose.Cells:

- Aspose.Words: [How to Find and Highlight Text](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Find+and+Replace#FindandReplace-HowtoFindandHighlightText)
- Aspose.Cells: [Find or Search Data](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Find+or+Search+Data)
- Aspose.Cells: [Setting Colors and Background Patterns](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellsnet/Cells+Formatting#CellsFormatting-SettingColorsandBackgroundPatterns)

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.